# More elegant and faster way to serve data to user- Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have been working on one of my project and in one of its feature we retrieve the data from database and write it to a **Blob** instance and make it available to user to download. But as data is very very large like 15k+ pages in **.JSON** file with 8000000 words. the code snippet with which i am writing data to  that file is given. please suggest any other elegant and faster way because this is taking too much time and also freezing the machine for a while.

```
function bulk_download_json(label_id) {
    $.msg({
        //autoUnblock : false,
        clickUnblock : false,
        beforeUnblock: function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/initiate_download/?label=" + label_id,
                success: function(data) {

                    var bulk_mails = data;


                    bulk_download_filename = label_id.concat(".json");

                    var bulk_json_file = JSON.stringify(bulk_mails);

                    var a = window.document.createElement('a');
                    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([bulk_json_file], {
                        type: 'text/json'
                    }));
                    a.download = bulk_download_filename;

                    // Append anchor to body.
                    document.body.appendChild(a)
                    a.click();

                    // Remove anchor from body
                    document.body.removeChild(a)

                    remove_bulk_data(label_id);
                }
            });
         //self.unblock();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pagination for this where you will pass on the page_no and limit for the records being fetched

[Refer] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/pagination/